# A function implementation to cut a portion of a link list and append it to the end of the list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Consider the following function :

```
void CustomAppender(int totalNodesToSkip, int totalNodesToCut);
```

Here `totalNodesToSkip` and `totalNodesToCut` are both the inputs given. So it is required to cut a portion of a given linklist of length `totalNodesToCut` from the `totalNodesToSkip` numbered node from the beginning.

Consider the list following:

`List_1`:   `a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h->i->j->k`

Input to the function is `CustomAppender(2,3)`.

Then in the first pass it should the list should become:

`List_2`:       `a->b->f->g->h->i->j->k->c->d->e.`
So here the portion c->d->e moved to the tail. And this process need to be repeated untill we reach to the end of the given list. That is we need to stop when we reach node 'k' of list 1.

To solve the problem simple approach is by according to the given input take the portion to cut as:
Keep a marker to the end point 'k' in *Marker.

1. *startPTR pointing node c.
2. *endPTR pointing node e.  (Both can be iterated with the given input.)
3. And point b nodes next as endPTR's next.
4. 'k' node's next points to startPTR.
5. Finally endPTR points to NULL.
6. Above steps can be repeated untill we reach the Marker.

This is working fine.

But my question is is there anyway to implement it in any different way so that I use lesser pointers and much faster approach. As this procedure is costing O(n^2) runtime.

Please suggest any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single pass of the list.

```
starting at the head of the list, move forward `(skip-1)` nodes. Call this `skip_ptr`.
start another pointer, call it `glue_ptr`. Move it forward `(cut-1)` nodes.
```

At this point, `skip_ptr` references the last node to be skipped and `glue_ptr` references the last node to be cut.

Now, glue them together and mark the end of the cut list.

```
cut_ptr = skip_ptr.next;  // save c->d->e
skip_ptr.next = glue_ptr.next; // attach a->b to f->g ...
glue_ptr.next = null; // mark e as the end of the cut list
```

So now you have `a->b->f->g->h->i->j->k`, and `cut_ptr` points to `c->d->e`.

Now, if you set `glue_ptr = skip_ptr.next` and move `glue_ptr` forward until `glue_ptr.next == null`, you can then write:

```
glue_ptr.next = cut_ptr;  // attaches the cut part to the end of the list
```

You just have to keep track of the pieces. But it does the operation in a single pass: O(n).

### Update

If you have to *repeatedly* skip and cut so that the original list:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k
```

becomes

```
a,b,f,g,k,c,d,e,h,i,j
```

You can still do it with a single pass over the list. Here's C# code that shows how it's done. Should be easily converted to C.

```
private void CustomAppender(LLNode list, int skip, int cut)
{
    LLNode skip_ptr = list;
    LLNode cut_list = null;
    LLNode cut_ptr = null;

    while (skip_ptr.Next != null)
    {
        // skip over 'skip' items
        for (int i = 1; i < skip && skip_ptr.Next != null; ++i)
        {
            skip_ptr = skip_ptr.Next;
        }

        // skip_ptr.next is the start of the next group we want to cut.
        // move forward to the last node to be cut.
        for (int i = 0; i < cut && skip_ptr.Next != null; ++i)
        {
            LLNode nodeToCut = skip_ptr.Next;
            skip_ptr.Next = nodeToCut.Next;
            nodeToCut.Next = null;
            if (cut_list == null)
            {
                cut_list = nodeToCut;
            }
            else
            {
                cut_ptr.Next = nodeToCut;
            }
            cut_ptr = nodeToCut;
        }
        if (skip_ptr.Next != null)
            skip_ptr = skip_ptr.Next;
    }
    // So now we have two lists.
    // skip_ptr points to the last node in the list.
    // Append cut_list to the end.
    skip_ptr.Next = cut_list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim for your reply. But this will only give the list in first pass. I need to do it repeatedly until I reach the last node. For example I have a list of 1000 nodes then I had to do it repeatedly after 2 nodes cutting a portion of length 3 nodes unless I reach the end of the list. And that end is the end of the list which I should mark before doing any alteration to the list.

Comment: @Shantanu: Are you saying that you have to *repeatedly* skip 2 and cut 3, so that ultimately you'd have `a->b->f->g->k->c->d->e->g->h->i`? If so, you can still do it in a single scan. Just maintain a pointer to the end of the cut list and keep tacking cut portions onto it. When you reach the end of the original list, you tack on the list of cut portions. It's still a single scan of the list.

Comment: Yes exactly I have to repeatedly do it. Whatever you are suggesting the same thing I had described in the problem. Ultimately you have to run atleast two one nested loop.

Comment: Yes exactly I have to repeatedly do it. Whatever you are suggesting the same thing I had described in the problem. Ultimately you have to run atleast two one nested loop.

`for(PTR = Head; Run untill end of the list; PTR = PTR->Next) // Outer loop to iterate through the list.
{
         for()//Inner loop to cut the nodes and append to end of the list

}

`

Hence two loops, so O(n^2).

Comment: @Shantanu: You can still do it in a single scan of the list. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

i first of count the total number of elements. As we have to do splitting in elemenys into 3 chains. Now from total subtract the skipped numbers. As split the chain i.e

```
  a->b c->d->e->f-g->h->i->j->k
```

Now, we have the number left. Now take yhe modulus of remanin number. in case module is 0 then do nothing else whatevey number comes split from last after counting.

As in above you have taken 3 thus no operation is needed to reveser thing but in of 2 the split out be as:

```
a->b c->d->e->f-g->h->i->j k
```

now change the last element chain 2 second element chain thus :

```
 a->b k c->d->e->f-g->h->i->j
```

now combine them

```
 a->b->k->c->d->e->f-g->h->i->j
```

Comment: I don't think that it will work. Because following is the result of the list after cutting iteratively till the end of list.  
Original List:  `a->b->c->d->e->f-g->h->i->j->k`    

Pass_1: Cutting from c to e and iterating pointer pointing b.  Result is: `a->b->f->g->h->i->j->k->c->d->e`    

Pass_2: Cutting from h to j and iterate pointer pointing g.  
Result is: `a->b->f->g->k->c->d->e->h->i->j`    

Pass_3: Here the iterating pointer on incrementing once reaches the node k which was the last node in the parent list. Hence terminating condition reached and process complete.

Comment: @Shantanu But the f->g->k which clears the condition of 3 variables + end marker. Another thing the Number of Steps do cutting and linking require more steps. But with my formula you have to cutting only only which is optimized doing same work. In case of modules == 0 then you can do things for that condition. You can change things according to your needs its the basic Idea to do things..

Comment: With your approach I think the solution is not correct. Sorry if I sound rude.